# Can this query be improved? view for few count totals on a table

Tags: sql-server

I am not a dba but I am trying to create an effecient query for a view that will return some totals on a table

```
select 
 (select count(1) from alerts) as Total,
 (select count(1) from alerts where iscomplete is null or iscomplete = 0) as Active,
 (select count(1) from alerts where iscomplete = 1) as Complete
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `CASE` so that only one full scan is needed. An non-clustered index on iscomplete will cover this query.

```
SELECT
      COUNT(1) AS Total
    , SUM(CASE WHEN iscomplete is null or iscomplete = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Active
    , SUM(CASE WHEN iscomplete = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Complete
FROM dbo.alerts;
```

Comment: You could shorten the second a bit by inverting the check and a bit more with IIF `SUM(IIF(iscomplete <> 0, 0,1)) `

Comment: @MartinSmith wouldn't it be faster to use the other 2 calculations? `COUNT(1) - SUM(CASE WHEN iscomplete = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Active` (Assuming that 0 and 1 are the only options for `iscomplete`)

Comment: And the 3rd calculation could just be `SUM(iscomplete) AS Complete` - under the same assumption.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - Assuming iscomplete is data type bit you can't use SUM on it. You could cast it to integer but I don't know if that would save you anything.

Comment: I did a blog post about this many years ago that might help explain this technique: http://blog.sqlconcepts.co.nz/2011/12/t-sql-tuesday-25-t-sql-tricks-selective.html